# Solving vector equations.

Tags: vectors

If I'm given any two non collinear vectors $c$ and $b$ and any other vector $a$, then what is the equivalent of
$(a\cdot b)b + (a\cdot c)c +[a\cdot(b×c)](b×c)/|b×c|^2$
The options given are: $a$ vector, $b$ vector, $c$ vector or none of these.

Comment: Do you mean "any other vector c"?

Comment: also are you missing a $/|b|^2$ and $/|c|^2$ in the first two terms of the sum?

Comment: I've made changes in the first line, but the expression to be simplified is the same.

Comment: In general, none of these. In the special case that $b, c$ are unit vector orthogonal to each other, the expression produces $a$.